# How to generate a thermal picture using C++ and OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working on my school project. I use grid-eye to access the environment temperature. The data form is a 64 pixels array (8x8 2D-array). Now I want to use this array to generate a thermal picture. I can simply copy the value to Matlab, scale it, and use image (temperature) to output a picture like this

[image]

The more red and dark represent hotter.
But I build all program in C++. So I have to find a way to do the same thing in C++. The first thing I though is OpenCV. After some searching, I wrote a simple code for only gray-scale mat. But this image looks weird.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
void GridEye::showCV() {
    // > threshold means this pixel contain heat object.

    for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
        if (temperature[i] > threshold) forimage[i] = 255;
        else forimage[i] = 0;
    } 

    Mat image(8, 8, CV_8UC1, forimage);
    resize(image, image, Size(640, 640)); // to make picture larger
    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Display window", image);
    waitKey(100);
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code? Or some suggestion for using other library because I am really not familiar to OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
Mat1f image(8, 8, temperature);
//threshold(image, image, your_threshold_value, 0, THRESH_TOZERO); // << Uncomment this line to apply a threshold 
normalize(image, image, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX);
imshow("original size", image);
Mat resized;
//resize(image, resized, Size(640, 640)); // << Apply bilinear interpolation
resize(image, resized, Size(640, 640), 0, 0, INTER_NEAREST);
imshow("resized", resized);
waitKey();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But after normalizing the image become more weird.

Comment: value of threshold? Which is the range of the values in temperature?

Comment: I usually set threshold to 21. The range is 16~24.

Comment: were you applying the threshold in matlab also?

Comment: No. The code above is a simple thought. If the value greater than threshold, I'll let opencv show this pixel white and vice versa. But actually I want to do the same thing in matlab image(). Because this concept will output a discrete picture but I want to output more continous picture. Here is the picture for using normalize on temperature array and corresponding temperature array value.
[Here](http://imgur.com/i8eKNnt)

Comment: Seems workable. But I wonder why there is always two gray line there.[Picture](http://imgur.com/v2CDXjX)

Comment: should work well now. Since you have float values, better store them in a `Mat1f` instead of a `Mat1b`. To display `Mat1f`, values must be in [0,1] range.